# How to find the sklearn version of pickled model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

I have a pickled sklearn model, which I need to get to run. This model, however, is trained in unknown version of sklearn.

When I look up the model in debugger, I find that there is a bunch of strange tracebacks inside, instead of the keys you'd expect, for example:

```
decision_function -> 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'decision_function'
fit_predict -> 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'fit_predict'
score_samples -> 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'score_samples'
```

How can I get this model to run? Does these error message hint you anything?

EDIT: The solution is to brute force search the sklearn version. In my case when I got to the correct major version, the error message pointed me to the correct minor version.

Comment: Does `python -m pickletools your_pickled_model_file` show the `'_sklearn_version'` within the first 100 lines or so?

Answer (score 1):

Just like @rickhg12hs suggested, the `python -m pickletools your_pickled_model_file` does the job!

The output is quite long, so I recommend using head:
`python -m pickletools your_pickled_model_file | head -100`

Comment: Or maybe even `python -m pickletools your_pickled_model_file | grep -A 2 -F _sklearn_version`.

Answer (score 0):

You can know the version of a pickled model after scikit-learn 0.18. Using

```py
model.__getstate__()['_sklearn_version']
```

So at least you will know if it is pre 0.18 or newer.

Comment: If I get any value, then I know that it is >= 0.18, right? I have checked the value in this field and found, that it is set to the sklearn version that is currently installed.

Comment: Apparently, this does not work well. As after you loaded the model `model.__getstate__()` will set `_sklearn_version` to your version currently installed. As you can see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913be6d7e485b792ea36e9268be31ed52d0/sklearn/base.py#L316)

Comment: Yes. The only option is to brute force search the sklearn versions. When I got to the correct major version, the error message told me what the minor version should be.